# Which steps to follow in order to make configuration of NAPTR records in ejabberd

Tags: configuration, xmpp, ejabberd

I am newly in network and programming. I want to configure Sip in ejabberd.
After I added ejabberd_sip listening module in ejabberd.yml  as recommended in
the [documentation](https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/listen/#ejabberd-sip-1) the next step is described as below:

> Next you need to configure DNS SIP records for your virtual domains.
> Refer to RFC 3263 for the detailed explanation. Simply put, you should
> add NAPTR and SRV records for your domains. Skip NAPTR configuration
> if your DNS provider doesn't support this type of records. It’s not
> fatal, however, highly recommended.

The problem is I don't know where and How to do it.
I am running ejabberd server on localhost in windows 10 system.

Answer (score 0):

Given they're **DNS** SIP records, and that they rely on your **DNS** provider supporting them, I think the documentation makes it pretty clear it's **DNS**.

Given you're running on localhost, don't expect to find a DNS provider that supports them. Forget it and move on, it's not mandatory and you're likely running an alpha deployment anyway.

*(If this is not an alpha deployment, setup DNS beforehand and move away from localhost).*